# How to merge rows in a jqxgrid when row values are same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I need to merge cells in a jqxgrid which has same row values. Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This [jQuery Grid](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm), does not have cells merge capabilities according to the web site's demos and documentation. I think that this feature is not available. Otherwise, jQWidgets would have listed it on the [https://jqwidgets.com/](https://www.jqwidgets.com/), because cells merge is an important feature with much sell value. However, it is best also to ask the jQWidgets team, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.